# Missing に particle: ごろ vs ごろに

Tags: particle-に

I am studying Genki I at the moment and I stumbled across the following sentence:

私はよく**七時ごろ**うちへ帰ります

I understand that the meaning is "I often return home at around 7 o'clock".
But I feel like we are missing the に particle after 七時ごろ here.

Does ごろ / ごろに ***replace*** the に particle?
If so, what is the difference betwen them two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

に can be omitted after ごろ. The following two sentences are both correct and they mean the same thing.

> 私はよく七時ごろうちへ帰ります
>
> 私はよく七時ごろ**に**うちへ帰ります

By the way, you can use ぐらい instead of ごろ, but in this case に can’t be omitted.

> x 私はよく七時ぐらいうちへ帰ります

It must be:

> 私はよく七時ぐらい**に**うちへ帰ります